# Insert Formula to Cell using VBA - Not Working

Tags: vba

I am trying to insert a formula into a macro, but when I run the macro, it gets stuck at the formula. This is the format I'm using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(ROUND(AVERAGE(D16:D75),3)), "", ROUND(AVERAGE(D16:D75), 3))"
```

Comment: Change `""` to `""""`

Comment: @ScottCraner Awesome - thank you! How do I give you a thumbs up?

Comment: Also it can be shortened with IFERROR():  `"=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGE(D16:D75),3), """")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes because they mess up with the string. Try replacing them with CHR(34)

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value = "=IF(ISERROR(ROUND(AVERAGE(D16:D75),3))," & CHR(34) & CHR(34) & ", ROUND(AVERAGE(D16:D75), 3))"
```

Eventually you can use doubled quotes (""""), but I find that quite difficult to read.